# Python Context Manager for asyncpg

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I'm trying to build a context manager for asyncpg, but so far, I got `AttributeError: __enter__`, this is what I've tried.
Alsgo I've tried using `def __enter__` without async, but doesn't work

What would be the right way to do it?

```
import asyncpg
import asyncio


class DatabaseConnection(object):

    def __init__(self, host, port, database, user, password):
        self.connection = None
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.database = database
        self.user = user
        self.password = password

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.connection = await asyncpg.connect(host=self.host,
                                                port=self.port,
                                                database=self.database,
                                                user=self.user,
                                                password=self.password)
        return self.connection

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        # its executed when connection close
        self.connection.close()
```

Then try to use it

```
async def get_time():
    with DatabaseConnection(host=DB_HOST, port=DB_PORT,
                            database=DB_NAME, user=DB_USER,
                            password=DB_PASSWORD) as connection:
        values = await connection.fetch('''SELECT * CURRENT_TIME''')
        print(values)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(get_time())
```

Comment: You should use `async with` for an asynchronous context manager

Comment: thanks, this gave me a hint of what was wrong, also was missing the async def and inside await

Answer (score 0):

For people end up here from search, here is a complete example:

```py
class AsyncDatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self, **params):
        self.connection = None
        self.params = params

    async def __aenter__(self):
        self.connection = await asyncpg.connect(**self.params)
        return self.connection

    async def __aexit__(self, *_):
        await self.connection.close()


async def get_data():
    async with AsyncDatabaseConnection(host="db", database="dbname", user="username", password="pass") as conn:
        return await conn.fetchrow("""SELECT * FROM some_table LIMIT 1;""")
```